# Regular expression <.*?>

Tags: python, nlp

I'm new to Python, and have been looking at text cleaning examples such as [this](https://www.kaggle.com/shashanksai/text-preprocessing-using-python/data) on Kaggle, and had a few questions on the stemming and stopwords part.

```
for sentence in final_X:
  sentence = sentence.lower()                 # Converting to lowercase
  cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
  sentence = re.sub(cleanr, ' ', sentence)        #Removing HTML tags
  sentence = re.sub(r'[?|!|\'|"|#]',r'',sentence)
  sentence = re.sub(r'[.|,|)|(|\|/]',r' ',sentence)        #Removing Punctuations
```

What does `cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')` mean? I understand that it is used to remove HTML tags, but I'm confused as to what `<.*?>` means.

Comment: tags and title do not match your question. You want to understand a regular expression, and not just any but `<.*?>`, put that in the title!

Answer (score 2):

`<.*?>` is called a *regular expression pattern*. This pattern in particular looks for a `<` and then any number of characters `.*` followed by a `>`.
The period `.` denotes "any character" and the asterisk `*` denotes "0 or more times". The question mark `?` after the `*` is the lazy quantifier which indicates that it should consume as few characters as possible. This is important for a case like this:

`<p> 2 > 1 </p>`

If the question mark was not there, the pattern would match this:
**`<p> 2 > 1 </p>`**

Whereas if the question **is** there, it would look for the FIRST `>` that follows a `<` like this:
**`<p>`**`2 > 1`**`</p>`** which is the desired result

Answer (score 0):

This is a *regex* pattern.  This pattern `<.*?>` means a string with `<` followed  by any character (coded by the point) repeated any number of times (coded by the star) and finally `>` The question mark after the star is to make it lazy, that is the match stops at the first `>` encountered after `<`.

See   https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285 to learn more about regular expressions.

Actually, it can be

```
sentence = re.sub('<.*?>', ' ', sentence)
```

instead of

```
cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
sentence = re.sub(cleanr, ' ', sentence)
```

or else `cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')` should be before the `for` loop for optimization.